# Set multisite settings when new site created

Tags: multisite

I need to set some defaults for my multisite sites as they are created but It's not quite working. I have this in the `install.php` file in `/wp-content`:

```
function wporg_wpmu_new_blog( $blog_id, $user_id, $domain, $path, $site_id, $meta ) {
    update_blog_option( $blog_id, 'upload_url_path', 'http://mycdn.net/newsite' );
    update_blog_option( $blog_id, 'upload_path', '/home/www/myfiles/newsite' );
    update_blog_option( $blog_id, 'blog_public', '0' );

    switch_to_blog($blog_id);

    // Remove the default post & page
    wp_delete_post(1, true);
    wp_delete_post(2, true);

    // Remove the first comment
    wp_delete_comment( 1, true );

    restore_current_blog();
}
add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', 'wporg_wpmu_new_blog', 10, 6 );
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: what part is not "quite working"?

Comment: None of it. I forgot to mention this code is in my `index.php` file in the `wp-content` folder. (updated question)

Comment: In your question you say you have it in "install.php", in wp-content

Comment: I just updated it for anyone else who comes across the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`install.php` is only run during **installation**, it wont be run during new site creation.

You'd need to put that code in a [mu-plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) to have any chance of running.

(I guess it could also exist in a network-activated plugin, but I'm not 100% sure of that)

Add the following before your code, and put your file in `wp-content/mu-plugins`:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Yourmultisite options
Description: Foobar
Version: 1.0.0
Author: You
Author URI: http://www.examplecom
*/
```

Comment: `mu-plugins` don't run any activation hooks. I placed the code for that in the directory and it didn't have any effect either.

Comment: Did you create a plugin file in mu-plugins? Does it appear on the list of 'must use' plugins?

Comment: mu-plugins don't run "activation" hooks, but the action you want to hook onto, it's not an activation hook.

Comment: Ah, ok. I created the `mu-plugins` folder set permissions to `755` and loaded a `php` file in there with the above script but nothing changes when I view the site's settings.

Comment: You need to create an actual plugin file. It needs its plugin header. Update my answer with an example.

Comment: prefect, got it!